# How to limit separator input in Swift UITextField?

Tags: ios, swift

How do I embed this in a program to limit the input of delimiters in a text field?

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if(string == "," || string == "." ) {
        if ((textField.text?.contains(","))! || (textField.text?.contains("."))!){
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 4):

you can do

```
let stringName = texfeild.text?.replacingOccurrences(of: "...", with: ".", options: NSString.CompareOptions.literal, range: nil)
```

and for the comas:

```
let stringName = texfeild.text?.replacingOccurrences(of: ",,,", with: ",", options: NSString.CompareOptions.literal, range: nil)`
```

of course edit it to how you want it

assuming your only looking for `...` and `,,,`

You can use a set to filter your duplicated characters:

```
let str = "randomStringgg"
var set = Set<Character>()
let squeezed = str.filter{ set.insert($0).inserted }
```

`print(squeezed)`   //  "randomString"
Or as an extension on `RangeReplaceableCollection` which will also extend String and Substrings as well:

```
extension RangeReplaceableCollection where Element: Hashable {
    var squeezed: Self {
        var set = Set<Element>()
        return filter{ set.insert($0).inserted }
    }
}
let str = "randomStringgg"
print(str.squeezed)      //  "randomString"
print(str[...].squeezed) //  "randomString"
```

as for the constant updating for the textfeild I do no think you can do that, you can modify it after the user presses done and that's about it